# mySQL column without a one-size-fits-all precision for DECIMAL

Tags: mysql, database-design, precision

When I define a table to store decimal values I use a statement like this:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    myKey INT NOT NULL,
    myValue DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (myKey)
);
```

However, this results in every myValue being stored with a one-size-fits-all precision of (10,2).  For instance

```
45.6 becomes 45.60
21 becomes 21.00
17.008 becomes 17.01
```

But what if each record has a myValue of different precision?  I need 45.6 to remain 45.6, 21 to remain 21, and 17.008 to remain 17.008.  Otherwise the precision of measurement is being lost. There's a big difference between 21 and 21.00.

Comment: Could this [decimal, double, and float](http://net-informations.com/q/faq/float.html) difference information possibly help?

Comment: 17.008 is different from 17.01 I get that, but how is 21 different from 21.00 ? Are you using this numbers as strings? It is the only difference I can think of. To get your precision you need to know how many digits you need to your precision. Read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) for reference.

Comment: 21 implies it was only measured to nearest digit (e.g. true value could have been 21.3, but used ruler with only cm tick marks).

Comment: In that case, I think you need to store the method of measurement (or the tolerance) alongside the actual measurement.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to do greater/less-than compares, store as a `VARCHAR(..)`

The strings '21' and '21.00' would have identical values, but present different "precision".

When needing the numeric value, add zero (`col + 0`).

This does not allow for "negative precision", such as "1.2M" being represented as `1200000`.  If you need that, then Norbert's approach is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

You can store with high precision and exact recall by following a different way of storing the data:

Create a table with two columns:

```
CREATE TABLE precise (value BIGINT, decimaldot INT);
```

Use code to determine where the dot is, for example in your `21` value: 2 (assuming 1 indexing). So stored the value would be:

```
INSERT INTO precise values (21,2);
```

Retrieved it would return `21` exact (parsing back the dot in the value 21 at position 2, is 21)

Value 17.008 would also have decimaldot at 2:

```
INSERT INTO precise values (17008,2);
```

Etc..

Larger values can be stored by using a `VARCHAR(4000)` instead of a biginteger, or by using blob fields.

Comment: Thanks, this would be fine with one column (e.g. the example I posted), but my true tables have many columns and millions of rows I'm loading with load data infile.

Comment: Save some space, make it `decimaldot TINYINT`.